# Topology on a smooth manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $X\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a smooth manifold. I want to understand why $X$ is in fact a topological space. Is it simply because it inherits the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: Yes, manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ are always viewed as inheriting the subspace topology.